# How to have 2 framelayouts where one ends up as scrollview and the other as a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

So I have a layout that has two framelayouts that depending on situation are populated. I put them both in a scrollview so they can both be displayed completely.

First framelayout would refer to another layout that is a simple linear layout with long textviews

second framelayout would refer to a view that is a recyclerview

note that 
1- I do not want to have the first framelayout as the header to my recyclerview nor be added to the recyclerview.

2- I need to keep them separate hence why I have 2 framelayouts.

Issues -
1. it only shows the first framelayout which refers to a linear layout with long textviews  and only if I make its visibility gone it will show the second framelayout with its recyclerview

2. it only displays both if I give both framelayouts small heights but I need the heights to be wrap_content

   ```
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/competition_detail_dropdown_scrollview_linearlayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               >
                   <FrameLayout
                       android:id="@+id/competition_detail_dropdown_frame"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                       ></FrameLayout>
           </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


               <FrameLayout
                   android:id="@+id/frame_fragment"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                   ></FrameLayout>






       </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have included only the first `FrameLayout` within the `NestedScrollView`. The `NestedScrollView` should cover both.

I suggest you change the XML like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/competition_detail_dropdown_scrollview_linearlayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/competition_detail_dropdown_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can a nestedscrollview include more than one child ?

and also wouldnt the 2nd framelayout (recyclerview) being in a nestedscrollview affect its scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

try this
use `NestedScrollView` should cover both Framelayout.
 and set property of recyclerview `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

```
 <LinearLayout       
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <LinearLayout       
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/competition_detail_dropdown_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```